# Foreign Key de una tabla SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo saber a que tabla apuntan las foreign key de una tabla existente en mi base de datos usando SQL Server 2012 y sin ver el diagrama de tablas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Sp [sp_fkeys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Desde SQL 2008 tiene disponible el Sp [sp_fkeys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que te da información de las claves foráneas de cierta tabla, por ejemplo, lo siguiente te dice las tablas que tienen un FK a  'DTA_reports_database':

```
USE msdb;
EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = 'DTA_reports_database'
```

O bien, el camino inverso:

```
USE msdb;
EXEC sp_fkeys @fktable_name = 'DTA_reports_partitionfunction'
```

Parámetros de ejecución:

```
sp_fkeys [ @pktable_name = ] 'pktable_name'   
     [ , [ @pktable_owner = ] 'pktable_owner' ]   
     [ , [ @pktable_qualifier = ] 'pktable_qualifier' ]   
     { , [ @fktable_name = ] 'fktable_name' }   
     [ , [ @fktable_owner = ] 'fktable_owner' ]   
     [ , [ @fktable_qualifier = ] 'fktable_qualifier' ]
```

#### 2. Sp [sp_help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Te da mucha más información sobre la tabla en forma de distintos `recordsets`, en los últimos encotrarás información al respecto

```
sp_help @objname = 'DTA_reports_database'
sp_help @objname = 'DTA_reports_partitionfunction'
```

#### 3. Usando vistas del sistema

Por ejemplo mediante `sys.tables`, `sys.foreign_key_column` y `sys.columns`

```
SELECT  T1.name AS TablaPK,
    T2.name AS TablaFK,
    C.name  AS ColumnaFK
    FROM sys.tables T1
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS FK
        ON FK.referenced_object_id = T1.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables as T2
        on FK.parent_object_id = T2.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns as C
        ON FK.parent_object_id = C.object_id 
        AND FK.parent_column_id = C.column_id
    WHERE   T1.name = 'DTA_reports_database'
        -- T2.name = 'DTA_reports_partitionfunction' -- Busqueda inversa
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando las vistas de sistema puedes obtener bastante información acerca de las llaves foráneas.

```
SELECT  s.name AS nombre_schema,
        fk.name AS nombre_fk,
        po.name AS nombre_tabla,
        ro.name AS nombre_tabla_referenciada,
        fk.create_date,
        fk.modify_date,
        fk.delete_referential_action_desc,
        fk.update_referential_action_desc,
        fk.is_disabled,
        STUFF(( SELECT CHAR(10) + ', ' + pc.name + ' = ' + rc.name
                FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc 
                JOIN sys.columns pc ON fkc.parent_object_id = pc.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
                JOIN sys.columns rc ON fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
                WHERE fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 3, '') AS Columnas
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN sys.objects po ON fk.parent_object_id = po.object_id
JOIN sys.objects ro ON fk.referenced_object_id = ro.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON fk.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE po.name = 'NombreDeTuTabla';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tutabla'
```

Comment: El resultado de esa query me da vacio, solamente el nombre de las columnas. Usando esta consulta :
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'IssueManager.rol_usuario'

Comment: con qué usuario debe ejecutar la consulta?

Comment: Mira por favor [answer]. ¨Podrias explicar un poco mas tu respuesta?